# How can we execute particular line of code only once in main method in java?

Tags: java, methods

I have a jar file in which there is the main method, in that main method I have several lines of code, in which I want to execute specific code only once in jar file execution and other code should be running as many time main method is called by jar file.
Here is the image of the code[the first line UIConfigureJson configJson = new UIConfigureJson(); run only one time in jar file execution because this jar runs main method at every 15 minutes. so this line should be run only one time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VhKh.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to persist state between application instances (i.e. if the code needs to "remember" something between different runs), you need to save it to a file.

In your case, you should create a file the first time the main method is called and check if that file exists before running this line (and the file creation code)